# Make array from resources

Tags: android, arrays, resources

I have 5 images in resoureces called img1,img2,img3,img4,img5

How can I loop through them with `R.drawable.img` ?

Something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
  Bitmap spurs_orig = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.("img"+i));
}
```

I have tried to create an array, but it doesn't work

```
Object left_files[] = new Object[]{R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5};
```

Comment: use, int[] left_files = new int[]{R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.drawable.img1` is an resource id which is `int` in type. you can create array of int

```
int[] left_files = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, 
                      R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5};
```

Then iterate like

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  Bitmap spurs_orig = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, left_files[i]);
}
```

Comment: Or, you can iterate using the `for (int file : left_files)`. +1 for the answer anyway.